# zoom in on image does not work properly

Tags: mfc

in my mfc dialog application, got CimgDialog derived from Cdialog and CimgView derived from CScrollView.using StretchDIBits to display ImgBuf.how to zoom in using  CimgDialog::OnLButtonDown?. any code that works, sample code?. using my zoom code,  it zooms to wrong locations of image.

Comment: Show some code and explain what does not work and what you expect.

Comment: see blow. added comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following in your CImgView class:

```
double ZoomFactor = 1.5; // set to required value
CClientDC dc(this);
CSize sz = dc.GetViewportExt();
sz.x = (LONG) ((double) sz.x * ZoomFactor);
sz.y = (LONG) ((double) sz.y * ZoomFactor);
dc.SetViewportExt(sz);
```

`SetViewportExt()` has some restrictions -- see [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0e9z70dd.aspx).

If you are doing calculations using the `DC` (like page size, etc), it might be better to maintain the extent in your own member variable (e.g. `CSize m_totalDev`), change this value when you need to zoom and set up the viewport extent in `CImgView::OnPrepareDC()`, like

```
if (pDC->IsPrinting())
    // set up ViewPortExt depending on printer page size, fit-to-page, etc
else
    pDC->SetViewportExt(m_totalDev);
```

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tt73csz8.aspx) gives an example of how to set up the DC while printing.

The following articles may also help:

- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/doc_view/scrolling/article.php/c3345/Add-Zoom-and-Scale-Capabilities-to-CScrollView.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7348/CZoomView

Comment: at the point where you want to zoom in/out -- did you also take a look at the CodeProject article?

Comment: tried the examples in the links above, zoom still did not work. the dialog is cdialog based as opposed to cview based, this make a difference. I am using this code which I am trying to fix:             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493519/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-on-cscrollview-surface

Comment: You say in your question _CimgView derived from CScrollView_, how is `CImgView` connected to _CimgDialog derived from Cdialog_?

Comment: see this. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?243799-How-to-add-a-ScrollView-on-a-dialog

Comment: If you are using a view class derived from `CScrollView` (as per the codeguru link), incorporating the code from `CZoomView` (the codeproject article) into your `CImgView` class should work -- sorry, I have no further suggestions